# Is the 7 Inch LCD Display AT070TN90 compatible?

Tags: pi-3, screen, compatibility

Is the "7 Inch LCD Display AT070TN90 Compatible with AT070TN92 800×480" compatible with the Raspberry Pi 3?

[Amazon Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FECLJ4A)

Also, would i need any drivers, or could i just plug it in the DSI port?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the "7 Inch LCD Display AT070TN90 Compatible with AT070TN92 800×480" compatible with the Raspberry Pi 3?

No, or at least not without more hardware because...

> could i just plug it in the DSI port?

That's not a DSI ribbon.  I believe there are screens very similar to this used with the Pi, but there is an adaptor board in the middle.  That obviously doesn't include one.

Comment: Thanks? I don't know if this questions is out of place or not, but do you know of any good cheap screen for the Raspberry Pi 3? Under $40 and that's on Amazon or at Micro Center.